# Any number of POST variables into an array

Tags: php, jquery

Might seem like a stupid question, but I'm having an issue creating an array from multiple POST variables. They are coming from a jQuery form that can have any number of variables. It can be 1 of 2 options, name or school.

For example: `$_POST['name1']`, `$_POST['school2']`, `$_POST['name3']`, `$_POST['name4']`, etc.

Is there a way to get the max number of variables and put each variable into an array? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: `$_POST` is already an array.... what else do you want? Do you want to separate the `name` and `school` entries?

Comment: What is the max number of variables?

Comment: Did you want something like extract()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<input name="name[]" />
<input name="school[]" />
<input name="name[]" />
<input name="name[]" />
```

Is that what you mean? [PHP Form Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) Then, reference wise, you now have an array for `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['school']`

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $name)
{
  // each form element from the `name[]` inputs = $name
}
foreach ($_POST['school'] as $school)
{
  // each form element from the `school[]` inputs = $name
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you're numbering them you can use a foreach on the $_POST variable:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
{
  if (preg_match('/^name\d+$/',$key){
    // name variable
  } else if (preg_match('/^school\d+$/',$key){
    // school variable
  }
}
```

Comment: by the way.. there is no nearly no limit for the number of variables in the post. but you may run into your post_max_size...

Comment: Hello @Flask if there are the huge number of post variables yes it might run into post_max_size. Can you please suggest how to handle such issue. Can we use ajax method to submit those huge post variables? Will it again run post_max_size issue using ajax as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can set  `name[1]` (or `name[]`) as name of variable instead of `name`
In this case in `PHP` You will get array `$_POST['name']`

Comment: You can set name1, name2,... etc. But using arrays can make more sense depending on the application/data. For example if you are always going to have address1,2, and 3, then an array would be overkill.

Comment: @Colin, I know I can, probably here problem is in my English. Hope now answer is more obvious?

Comment: Your edit does make it a bit clearer, but I was just pointing out that arrays may not always be the best solution, just as having statically numbered post args may not be the best either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  // parse key names / etc
}
```

This would allow you to go through ALL post arguments. But be careful, there are potential security risks. You will have to validate you post key/names very carefully (you should always be doing this though).

Answer (score 0):

Try submitting your form with input field names like `school[]` and `name[]`. These should be properly transformed into arrays in your `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

You can count elements in `$_POST` array by invoking `count($_POST)`.

But yes, there is a better way of passing variables through jQuery:

```
jQuery.post('/your/url/here', {
    'name': ['Tom', 'Jerry', 'Garfield'], // passing array...
    'school': ['MIT', 'UCLA', 'Florida State University'] // ...and another one
}, function(data){
    // your callback here
});
```

and you will be able to count specific parts of the data like that (in PHP):

```
$number_of_names = count($_POST['name']); // $_POST is multidimensional array
$number_of_schools = count($_POST['school']);
```

or you can display them (still in PHP):

```
echo 'names: ' . implode(', ',$_POST['name']) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'schools: ' . implode(', ',$_POST['school']) . PHP_EOL;
```

Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got now what you mean;

```
$options = Array( "school" => Array(), "names" => Array());
$i = 0;
foreach($options as $key => $val){
    while( isset($_POST[$key.$i] ) && ++$i ){
        $options[$key] += $_POST[$key.$i];
    }
}
```

Form arrays may be a better option unless they hinder some other underlying functionality

simpler:

```
$myNames = Array();
for($i=0; $i<1000; $i++){
if( !isset($_POST["school$i"])): 
    break;
 $myNames += $_POST["school$i"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the input on the form would be best, as everyone else is recommending. If that's not really feasible for some reason, you'll have to manually create an array:

```
$base_names = array('name' => array(), 'school' => array());
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $key = preg_replace('/\d+$/', '', $key);
    if (isset($base_names[$key])) {
        $base_names[$key][] = $value;
    }
}
```